# Out of Browser Application Installation

Tags: c#, silverlight

Can out of browser installation be made in places other than desktop and start menu? If possible what change must be made in AppManifest.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just uncomment the Deployment.Application element in your AppMainfest.xml

Edit:
Further Information [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-3-as-a-Desktop-Application-Out-of-Browser-Applications.aspx)

Comment: Hi Henrik ,
 The appication will be installed either in start menu or desktop
my doubt is weather it can be installed in drives like d:\